# splitcontainer splitterdistance for panel 2

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, splitter

I use Windows Forms `SplitContainer`. I want set the `SplitterDistance` value but for the `Panel2` instead `Panel1`. Is it possible ?

When I set `SplitterDistance`, it sets the distance based on first panel, while I want to set the distance based on second panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the distance based on width or height of control.

For example in a horizontal `SplitterContainer` when you want to set distance from bottom to 50, use such code:

```
splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = splitContainer1.Height - splitContainer1.SplitterWidth 
                                   - 50;
```

For a vertical `SplitterContainer` use width of control.